# Loading async image in Angular2+Electron app after selecting directory from dialog

Tags: image, angular, electron, observable

So I have the following in an Electron+Angular2 app:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import * as fs from "fs";
import {ImageFile, KeepAction, RetouchAction, PrivateAction, DeleteAction} from "./components/imageFile";
import {remote} from 'electron';
import {
    DomSanitizationService,
        SafeUrl
} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";


let dialog = remote.dialog;

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <button id="openDir" (click)="openDir()">Open</button>
        <br />
        <img id="processingImage" [src]="currentImg | async"/>
        <br />
        <button id="nextImage" (click)="nextImage()">Next Image</button>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {

    dirPath: string;
    currentImg: Observable<SafeUrl>;
    fileSet: string[] = [];
    currentFile: number = 0;

    constructor(private sanitization: DomSanitizationService) {
        this.dirPath = "";
        this.currentImg = Observable.of<SafeUrl>(null);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Shows a dialog for opening the directory to be processed.</p>
     * <p>After a directory is selected, it will be analyzed and all images will be loaded to be organized.</p>
     */
    openDir() {
        dialog.showOpenDialog({defaultPath: 'C:\\', properties: ['openDirectory']}, (fileNames) => {
            //TODO assert only one file name is present
            this.dirPath = fileNames[0];
            fs.readdir(this.dirPath, (e, f) => this.loadFiles(e, f));
        });
    }

    nextImage() {
        if (this.currentFile < this.fileSet.length - 1) {
            this.currentFile++;
            this.setSanitizedCurrentImage();
        }
    }

    setSanitizedCurrentImage(){
        let currentPath = this.fileSet[this.currentFile];
        this.currentImg = Observable.of(this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(currentPath));
    }

    loadFiles(err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, files: string[]): void {
        this.fileSet = [];
        this.currentFile = 0;

        files.forEach((it) => {
            var filePath = this.dirPath + '/' + it;

            if (fs.statSync(filePath).isFile()) {
                this.fileSet.push(filePath);
            }
        });
        this.setSanitizedCurrentImage();
    }

}
```

When hitting the Open button, a dialog appears, I select a directory and try to load the first image with `setSanitizedCurrentImage()` it works on `nextImage` but not on the open image.

I guess it's due to the async method `showOpenDialog()` or `showOpenDialog()` but I'm not been able to get to refresh the current image value.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the state of `this.fileSet[this.currentFile]` on the first call. `this.currentFile` should be 0 then, so maybe your `this.fileSet` is doing something weird with the first file in the set.

Comment: I was able to do it with a Promise, will post ASAP the result.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using a `Promise` and resolving it after both the `showOpenDialog` and `readdir` callbacks were executed.

**TLDR**:

```
 openDir() {
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            dialog.showOpenDialog({defaultPath: 'C:\\', properties: ['openDirectory']}, (fileNames) => {
                //TODO assert only one file name is present
                this.dirPath = fileNames[0];
                fs.readdir(this.dirPath, (e, f) => {
                    this.loadFiles(e, f);
                    resolve();
                });
            })
        }).then(() => this.setSanitizedCurrentImage());
    }
```

Full code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import * as fs from "fs";
import {ImageFile, KeepAction, RetouchAction, PrivateAction, DeleteAction} from "./components/imageFile";
import {remote} from 'electron';
import {
    DomSanitizationService,
        SafeUrl
} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";


let dialog = remote.dialog;

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <button id="openDir" (click)="openDir()">Open</button>
        <br />
        <img id="processingImage" [src]="currentImg | async"/>
        <br />
        <button id="nextImage" (click)="nextImage()">Next Image</button>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {

    dirPath: string;
    currentImg: Observable<SafeUrl>;
    fileSet: string[] = [];
    currentFile: number = 0;

    constructor(private sanitization: DomSanitizationService) {
        this.dirPath = "";
        this.currentImg = Observable.of<SafeUrl>(null);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Shows a dialog for opening the directory to be processed.</p>
     * <p>After a directory is selected, it will be analyzed and all images will be loaded to be organized.</p>
     */
    openDir() {
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            dialog.showOpenDialog({defaultPath: 'C:\\', properties: ['openDirectory']}, (fileNames) => {
                //TODO assert only one file name is present
                this.dirPath = fileNames[0];
                fs.readdir(this.dirPath, (e, f) => {
                    this.loadFiles(e, f);
                    resolve();
                });
            })
        }).then(() => this.setSanitizedCurrentImage());
    }

    nextImage() {
        if (this.currentFile < this.fileSet.length - 1) {
            this.currentFile++;
            this.setSanitizedCurrentImage();
        }
    }

    setSanitizedCurrentImage(){
        let currentPath = this.fileSet[this.currentFile];
        this.currentImg = Observable.of(this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(currentPath));
    }

    loadFiles(err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, files: string[]): void {
        this.fileSet = [];
        this.currentFile = 0;

        files.forEach((it) => {
            var filePath = this.dirPath + '/' + it;

            if (fs.statSync(filePath).isFile()) {
                this.fileSet.push(filePath);
            }
        });
    }

}
```